# Require more clarity on `custom Directive` - in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a login form in my application. i decide to show the error on `blur` of my `input` element.

It works, but i have no.of question from my custom diretive. ( actually i made this directive using tutorial which is not explains anything)

here my code with html: i have put all my question with appropirate js lines. any one please help me to understand all this `directive` please?

My HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myNewApp" id="container">
    <div ng-controller="loginCont">
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
<form class="form" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="userLogin()">
    <div class="from-group" ng-class="{'has-error':loginForm.email.$invalid && loginForm.email.$dirty, 'has-success':loginForm.email.$valid && loginForm.email.$dirty}">
        <label for="emial">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" name="email" required cu-focus  />
        <span ng-show="loginForm.email.$invalid && loginForm.email.$dirty && !loginForm.email.focused">Wrong Email</span>
    </div>
    <div class="from-group">
        <label for="password">Email</label>
        <input type="password"  class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" name="password" required cs-focus >
        <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$invalid && loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.submitted">Wrong Password</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" type="submit">Login In</button>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

My js: with all my doubts.

```
var app = angular.module('myNewApp', [])
    .controller('loginCont', ['$scope', function ($scope) { //what is different from directive controller?
        $scope.name = 'Angular';
    }])

angular.module('myNewApp')
    .directive('cuFocus', function () {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                require :'ngModel', //why ngModel require here what it's doing here? what else we can pick further?
                link : function (scope, element, attr, controller) { //what is controller here?
                    controller.focused = false; //how !loginForm.email.focused connected to controller here?
                    element.bind('focus', function (e) {
                        scope.$apply(function(){ //why should apply intead controller.focused = true;
                            controller.focused = true; //how this update there in span attribute?
                        });
                    })
                    .bind('blur', function (e) {
                        scope.$apply(function(){    
                            controller.focused = false;
                        });
                    })
                }
            }
    });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/ucb7smxb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why ngModel require here what it's doing here? what else we can pick further?
   -means ng-model should be used on same element
2. what is controller here?
   Controller of ng-model directive, since you required ng-model you can inject it
3. how !loginForm.email.focused connected to controller here?
   This is usual value binding. You refer ng-model controller as 'controller' here in directive, when in html you refer it as 'loginForm.email'.
4. why should apply instead controller.focused = true;
   Cause binding is done standard js-event, so code inside listener  executes 'outside' angular, so to let angular know that model has changed you need to use $apply.
5. how this update there in span attribute?
   This is just usual value-binding. You refer ng-model controller as 'controller' here in directive, when in html you refer it as 'loginForm.email'.